Pyiceberg catalog in GCS: I cannot use pyceberg with google Cloud storage
I want to use the library pyiceberg with Google cloud storage.
I have a catalog created in Google Cloud storage using Pyspark and I would want to read this tables from there.
I see this documentation to create a catalog object for GSC, but I really don't understand how to connect to it or how to create a config object for google cloud.
I tried:
catalog = load_catalog(
    uri="gs://catalog",
    type="gcsfs"
)

but I get an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 catalog = load_catalog(
      2     name="gcsfs", 
      
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyceberg/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyiceberg/catalog/__init__.py:212, in load_catalog(name, **properties)
    210 catalog_type = None
    211 if provided_catalog_type and isinstance(provided_catalog_type, str):
--> 212     catalog_type = CatalogType[provided_catalog_type.upper()]
    213 elif not provided_catalog_type:
    214     catalog_type = infer_catalog_type(name, conf)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyceberg/lib/python3.11/enum.py:792, in EnumType.__getitem__(cls, name)
    788 def __getitem__(cls, name):
    789     """
    790     Return the member matching `name`.
    791     """
--> 792     return cls._member_map_[name]

KeyError: 'GCSFS'

I installed the package pypiceberg[gcsfs].
I see in the PYICEBERG github repository
AVAILABLE_CATALOGS: dict[CatalogType, Callable[[str, Properties], Catalog]] = {
    CatalogType.REST: load_rest,
    CatalogType.HIVE: load_hive,
    CatalogType.GLUE: load_glue,
    CatalogType.DYNAMODB: load_dynamodb,
    CatalogType.SQL: load_sql,
}



Is gcsfs installed in your environment?

Yes: gcsfs==2023.12.2.post1

Where do you intend to write the catalog i.e. the table names/metadata? The tables can be written to a cloud bucket but the catalogs need to be managed either in Hive metastore, server side via Rest API or a database.

I am quite new on this. Which one I should use to store the tables and read them together woth google cloud storage?

I wrote an answer in long form as a response to your question.

Pyiceberg is a python library for working with Iceberg tables.
First, get the OAuth2 token using the service account file.
I'm running this in a collab so I needed to get it done this way.
You could do this differently if running in a container.
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from pyiceberg import catalog


def get_access_token(service_account_file, scopes):
  """
  Retrieves an access token from Google Cloud Platform using service account credentials.

  Args:
      service_account_file: Path to the service account JSON key file.
      scopes: List of OAuth scopes required for your application.

  Returns:
      The access token as a string.
  """

  credentials, name = google.auth.load_credentials_from_file(
      service_account_file, scopes=scopes)

  request = Request()
  credentials.refresh(request)  # Forces token refresh if needed
  return credentials

# Example usage
service_account_file = "/path-to-service-account-file.json"  # Replace with your path
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]  # Adjust scopes as needed

access_token = get_access_token(service_account_file, scopes)


Next, the catalog is loaded.
We use the OAUTH2 credentials retrieved using our service account key.
I have redacted datetime_to_unix_ms function to focus on the main task.
Since you are just beginning, I suggest keeping your implementation light by using a database for your registry.
If you already have an EMR cluster up, you should look into using Hive metastore instead.
For this example, we will use an sqlite database for our central registry. You can replace this with any of the SQL database options supported by the SQLalchemy library.
REGISTRY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///catalog.db" # replace this with your database URI

catalog_inst = catalog.load_catalog(
    "default",
    **{
        "uri": REGISTRY_DATABASE_URI, 
        "py-io-impl": "pyiceberg.io.pyarrow.PyArrowFileIO",
        "gcs.oauth2.token-expires-at": datetime_to_unix_ms(access_token.expiry),
        "gcs.project-id": "project-id", # replace with your gcp project id
        "gcs.oauth2.token": access_token.token,
        "gcs.default-bucket-location": "gs://bucket/", # replace with your gcs bucket
        "warehouse": "gs://bucket/" # replace with your gcs bucket
    }
)

Finally, we create an example table with some data using Pyarrow:
import pyarrow as pa

catalog_inst.create_namespace("default") # Replace this with your namespace

# Define the schema for the book table
schema = pa.schema([
    ('title', pa.string())
])

catalog_inst.drop_table("default.books") # Replace this with your table
table = catalog_inst.create_table("default.books", schema=schema)

# Create some sample data
titles = ["The Lord of the Rings", "Pride and Prejudice", "Moby Dick"]

# Create Arrow arrays from the data
title_array = pa.array(titles, type=pa.string())
table_data = pa.Table.from_arrays([title_array], names=schema.names)

table.append(table_data)


It is storing the metadata in the sqlite database, but it cannot read or write the metadata in the google cloud storage bucket? like Pyspark does when selcting the hadoop catalog ?

I'm able to write the files to a bucket. Do you have the gcs.default-bucket-location, gcs.oauth2.token, gcs.oauth2.token-expires-at and warehouse options set.

Yes, I understand, I mean, that I don't want to use a separate database to store the metadata, I just want to store the metadata in the bucket as well as when I use pyspark with the catalog type hadoop.
I want to know if it is possible with pyiceberg

It is possible but not supported. You will need to implement a custom catalog to write the catalog to the gcs bucket. You can start with subclassing the MetastoreCatalog class
